# How to Debug the javascript on a webpage using only a android tablet?

Tags: javascript, android, debugging

I need to debug my JavaScript on my webpage. I know it has errors but I'm not sure what they are. How do I either view those errors from the browser (Chrome, Opera, Opera Mini or UC Broswer) of my android device or use a app that will define those errors?
I currently have no access to a computer for now. so I cannot USB Debug using any those methods. All I have is a tablet that is running Android 4.2 right now.

Comment: old school use alerts() `window.onerror = function (message, source, lineno, colno, error) { alert(message, source, lineno, colno, error); }`

Comment: I applaud your persistence to keep going without access to a PC.